# Deserializing a json object which isn't always of the same type

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm deserializing a json object to a class with Gson.fromJson(). Everything works fine except for one field which is giving me trouble. This field appears both as a boolean and as a field with subfields in the json. I have no idea what to do in my container class because making an inner class generates an error when the field appears as a boolean and vice-cersa. Here is an example of what the field can look like:

Either: `"licenses":false`

Or: `"licenses":{"models":["LicenseName1"]}}`

The easiest thing for me would be for the field be null when it appears as "false".

Sample code for the class being used to store the json data:

```
public class Test

{

    private License licenses //Or boolean licenses? Depends what's in the json...
    //More parameters...

    //Inner class
    public class License
    {
        String[] models;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you add some code it is easy to take if from there, like model class

Comment: I feel like you're approaching this backwards.  You should be thinking about how to construct your classes in a way that makes sense, and _then_ worrying about serialization/deserialization once the class structure is well-defined.

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys. I added sample code in the original post